# What values can OperatingSystem.Version have?

Tags: .net, windowsversion

The [`Environment.OSVersion` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion.aspx) can be used to get the version of the current OS. What value can its [`Version` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operatingsystem.version.aspx) have for the various OSes out there?

I'm interested only in the `Major` and `Minor` values and primarily about desktops OSes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [MSDN: Operating System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here we go http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/systeminformation/article.php/c8973/